# Tikz draw automata..

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

I've been able to draw the states, and the arrows between the states. It's the "labeling" around the automata I've got issues with ( I, E, P, and R).. Any ideas?

[image: Example]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you please provide us with what you have achieved to do?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: TikZ has a whole library for drawing automata. Are you using it? It makes lablelling connections between states simple.  But without showing your code it's hard to tell what you are doing. See [Which package can be used to draw automata?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/20784).

Comment: I agree with @AlanMunn. I also find it very hard to guess what your doing after my [crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells,column sep=3.14mm,row sep=3.14mm,
nodes={draw,circle,fill=cyan!50,minimum size=1cm}] (mat) {
 & & & \\
 & & & \\
};
\node[left=3.14mm of mat-1-1,font=\sffamily] {P};
\node[left=3.14mm of mat-2-1,font=\sffamily] {R};
\path ($(mat-1-1.north)!0.5!(mat-1-2.north)$) coordinate (x1)
($(mat-1-2.north)!0.5!(mat-1-3.north)$) coordinate (x2)
($(mat-1-3.north)!0.5!(mat-1-4.north)$) coordinate (x3)
($(mat-2-2.south)!0.5!(mat-2-3.south)$) coordinate (x4);
\node[above=3.14mm of x1,font=\sffamily] {I};
\node[above=3.14mm of x3,font=\sffamily] {E};
\draw[dotted] (x2) -- (x4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 61k rep and still not tired of answering do-it-for-me questions.  That's some real dedication.

Comment: @HenriMenke My willingness is inversely proportional to the reputation of the user. (You could just upvote those users to prevent me from answering these questions. ;-) A bit more seriously, there is a long discussion on whether or not one should ["educate" users](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7733/should-we-educate-new-users-by-not-answering-until). I see and respect the arguments of both sides, but my take on this is that (a) I do not educate users and (b) the answer is for everyone, not just the asker.

Comment: Thank you! I did not receive a notification that my answer had been answered.